# Filename-parsing logic in PySCIPOpt

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, scip

What are the allowed extensions for the parameter `filename` in `pyscipopt.Model.writeProblem(filename)`?

It works if `filename='a'`or `filename='a.mps'`,
but if e.g. `filename='a.problem'`, then it fails with the error code:

```
Exception: SCIP: a required plugin was not found !
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file extension is used to indicate the file format to write out the problem. The standard formats are CIP, MPS, and LP. The full list can be found [here](https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/group__FILEREADERS.php) and more formats can be supported by adding custom file readers.

There is no PROBLEM file format and that is why you got this error. You might have added a custom file reader to support PROBLEM files and that is why SCIP's error message is a bit cryptic here.

Comment: No, I haven't added anything. I just thought any filename is admissible, since I only want to read from PySCIPOpt, and the [documentation](https://scipopt.github.io/PySCIPOpt/docs/html/classpyscipopt_1_1scip_1_1Model.html#aaeea39150fbf007180b7ab7d8e476d2e) says only "the name of the file to be used". Can I submit a PR to the documentation?

Comment: Of course! PRs are always very welcome - even if it's "just" about documentation